# How to get particular part of string from an array of strings using javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hi below is array of strings

```
const arr = [
    "list/1/item/1/",
    "some-domain/2/item/2/",
    "item/3/",
    "some-domain/4/item/5/subitem/1/",
]
```

i have to filter those strings that start with  string "item/3/" or ends with string "item/3/"

so from above array expected filtered array is like below,

```
const filtered_arr = [
    "list/1/item/1/",
    "some-domain/2/item/2/",
    "item/3/",
]
```

from the filtered array i want to get the number after "/item/". so from above filtered array the expected output is

```
const arr_ids = ["1", "2", "3"]
```

what i have tried,

i have used below to match those strings that start or end with /item/3/

```
const filtered_arr = arr.map(str) => {
    return str.match(/item\/[0-9](\/)?$/g);
}
```

this gives the filtered_arr

```
const filtered_arr = [
    "list/1/item/1/",
    "some-domain/2/item/2/",
    "item/3/",
]
```

but how do i map through each array item and get the number after string "/item/".

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: "i have used below to match those strings that start or end with /item/3" but you are not checking 3 explicitly?

Comment: Your expected filtered array doesn't make sense. How is `item/3/` in that list? That clearly starts with `item/3/`, which you explicitly ruled out.

Comment: the number after item/ can be anything. like 3, 1 or any number

Comment: The question states _i have to filter those strings that start with string "item/3/" or ends with string "item/3"_ and we find element `item/3` which is not even present in the original array (the original array's element is `item/3/`). Please note: `item/3` is NOT `item/3/`. These are different strings.

Comment: sorry for the typo i have edited the array and the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter` to filter paths either starting or ending in `item/\d+/`.  Then use `map` to extract the item number from each matching path.

```js
const arr = [
    "list/1/item/1/",
    "some-domain/2/item/2/",
    "item/3/",
    "some-domain/4/item/5/subitem/1",
];
var output = arr.filter(x => x.match(/^item\/\d+|\bitem\/\d+\/$/))
                .map(x => x.match(/(?<=^item\/)\d+|(?<=\bitem\/)\d+(?=\/$)/)[0]);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: thanks but says object could be possibly null on map function

Comment: Your data has some problem.  My code is working with the sample data you actually provided.

Comment: yes there was a problem with the way i filter. now it works.

Comment: but this seems to also match the strings where the string item/3/ is followed by other string. for example it shouldnt match strings like "item/3/subitem/1" . meaning string item/3/ shouldnot be matched if its followed by another string. it can match only if its starts with item/3/ and has no following string or ends with item/3/. thanks

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

```
const filtered_arr = arr.map(str) => {
    const match = str.match(/\/item\/(\d)/);
    return(match[1]);
}
```